# Memory leak node js

Tags: node.js, memory, express

I have a memory leak on my nodejs application. In order to resume the purpose of the application, it's an api called by an iOS application and a backoffice to administrate some content.
The application is in production and we experience some memory leak due to utilisation.

The memory on the server is always going up and never going down.
I try to analyze the problem using node-heapdump.

First of all, i see a big difference between the heap size of the snapshot given by node-heapdump and the size taken by the app in the memory (heap size ~ 30Mb and RAM size ~ 100Mb), where that difference came from ?

Then i see an increment of the heap size just by refreshing a home page who does not return anything.
Is anyone has an idea of where my problem could be ?

For information i use nodejs version 0.10.x and expressjs 4.0.0

Thanks in advance guys.

**EDIT**

I install memwatch-next and the leak event is raised.
The error i have is this one :

> warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 leak listeners
>   added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

I try to set the defaultMaxListeners but when i stress the application the leak event is raised after sometime.
Does anyone knows what that error means ?

Comment: A home page that does not return anything?

Comment: For anything i mean not a json result or thing like that. So it's not because of a new memory allocation for an object that the memory went up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## have a look at memwatch-next

I had similar issues with the memwatch package and switched to memwatch-next and it installed without the node-gyp error and produced worked. As for the difference between the RSS and the heapdump , I am in the same boat as you are.

Comment: Thanks, the memwatch-next module actually work. I'll edit my post to put the result i have.

Comment: i use memwatch-next with heapdump to take the memory snapshot whenever the leak event occurs so that i can load those snapshot file in chrome and look for objects thats are consuming more memory but i am not able to diagnose exactly where those objects are been used in my code as it shows the strings object with highest count. Any luck with diagnosing the snapshot .

Answer (score 0):

Try to find memory leakage leak and stat from https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch.

Hope it would help.

Comment: I try to install memwatch through npm but it fails.
Failed at the memwatch@0.2.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the memwatch package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.

Did you have the same problem ?

Comment: you have to install python to order to use mematch as its uses some os apis to get data..make sure you seted up environment variable so python command can run from anywhere..

Comment: This still isn't working. Anyways memwatch will not give me more information that i already have with node-heapdump as the both show the heap size and repartition. Anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: @MartinStievenart install node-gyp package globally and it will fix the issue of installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this tool: [easy-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend you try running the application with the --inspect argument, this will then allow you to attach Chrome dev tools and take memory snapshots. From here take one at startup one during testing and then one after you have finished testing the application (no more requests to the application but must still be running.) This will allow you to see what exactly is causing the growth in memory.

From here you will be able to see what is causing the growth and hopefully an indication as to where the leak is.