# How to analyze memory leak in node js

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and I have developed a standalone application. Recently i observed that the memory used by this app is increasing continuously. so how can i analyze my code to know which part of code is eating memory.

Comment: Try [memwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch)

Comment: exactly the same google search query gives you a bunch of posts about it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory leak node js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672828/memory-leak-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Use node-inspector and analyse using Google developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of tools to debug Node.js app. Google search can provide you a lot of information in this area.
Any way the most popular solutions is using node-inspector.

Also you can use some tools to take a snapshots and then use this snapshot with Chrome DevTools for profiling. About this method you can check this link: http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/debugging-memory-leaks-node-js-applications

Also in Webstorm 10 available tools for profiling Node.js. More information about this you can check here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/07/node-js-profiling-in-webstorm-part-2-memory-profiling/