# Requesting large JSON objects lead to memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, needle.js

I have a simple NodeJs application that acts as a REST client and requests large JSON object. The problem is that it always runs out of memory (taking more than 6Gb). I am using manual garbage collection (app started with --expose_gc) but that doesn't seem to help much.

Here's my code:

```
var needle = require('needle');
function getAllData() {
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");

    setInterval(function () {
        getAllData();
    }, 10 * 1000);
}

function getDataFromUrl(url) {
    needle.get(url, function (error, response) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("do something");
        }
    });
}

function scheduleGc() {
    global.gc();
    setTimeout(function () {
        scheduleGc();
    }, 100 * 1000);
}

getAllData();
scheduleGc();
```

I have tried request library but I had the same results. What am I doing wrong?

P.s. My nodejs version is 6.9.1, needle version 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Use node inspector to find leakage. It could be internal nodejs leak or leakage from needle and request. I'd prefer to use native `http.request` to make sure it's not a library problem. Also you can split your code into independent parts and run them separately to find the leakage source.

There is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33914404/884491) how to detect memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an error. I was using the setInterval instead of setTimeout....

```
var needle = require('needle');
function getAllData() {
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
    getDataFromUrl("http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json");
}

function getDataFromUrl(url) {
    needle.get(url, function (error, response) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("do something");
        }
    });
}

function scheduleGc() {
    global.gc();

    setTimeout(function () {
        scheduleGc();
    }, 100 * 1000);
}

setInterval(function () {
    getAllData();
}, 10 * 1000);

scheduleGc();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are working with too much info, 6Gb should be treated with **streams**. 
 It's very easy with **needle**, just avoid the callback.
Here is an example:

```
'use strict';
 const needle = require('needle');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const out = fs.createWriteStream('bigFile.json');
 needle.get('http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json').pipe(out);
```

Comment: The JSON isn't 6Gb, it is a lot less. The 6Gb was the amount of used RAM due to the fact that I was using setInterval instead of setTimeout...